# Chrome Authentication popup custom message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, authentication

Chrome Authentication popup shows the message 'Requires user name and password' for basic authentication . Is it possible to change this message to a different one if required ?

In the response header , I am sending this text .

```
httpContext.Response.AppendHeader("WWW-Authenticate",
                    string.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", "Please enter your  RSA key"));
```

I am able to see the custom message in internet explorer but not in chrome .
Anyone facing this issue ?